# How to update document in Mongo CosmosDB with specific id

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have create function like this to update document in mongo cosmosDB in Azure. But I think this function will update any data, not data that I need

```
const updateDocuments = async(value, collectionName) => {
    const document = { value };
    const valueJSON = JSON.parse("{" + document.value + "}");
    const updateDocument = { $set: valueJSON };
    const DATABASE_COLLECTION_NAME = collectionName;
    if (!db)
        throw Error('updateDocuments::missing required params');
    const collection = await db.collection(DATABASE_COLLECTION_NAME);
    return await collection.updateOne(updateDocument);
}
```

Could anyone guide me on how to update a document I need to update? example like I would like to update 2 data that userName, userAge where userId is .... like that.

Thanks you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter to specify your filter condition and use it along with the 'updateDocument' in your code

Here is a document in my collection before update:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("6398326d159fbc54b028ce59"),
  userName: 'john123',
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Drews'
}
```

Code to find/filter by userName and change the last name to "Andrews":

```
async function main() {
    await client.connect();

    const db = client.db(dbName);
    const collection = db.collection("test_data");

    const filter = { "userName" : "john123" }; 

    const updateDoc = { "$set" : { 
                            "lastName": "Andrews" 
                        }
                    };

    return collection.updateOne(filter, updateDoc, { "upsert": false });

}
```

Resulting doc (same query as before):

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("6398326d159fbc54b028ce59"),
  userName: 'john123',
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Andrews'
}
```

Refer to the documentation here - https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/updateOne/